# Tuple to string with a function to each element

Tags: python

There is a tuple `(a, b, c)`.

I need to get `foo(a) + "\n" + foo(b) + "\n" + foo(c)`

How it can be done in a smart way, not manually?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You could do it this way (if foo() returns a string):

```
tuple_ = (a,b,c)
"\n".join( foo(i) for i in tuple_ )
```

if foo() doesn't return a string:

```
tuple_ = (a,b,c)
"\n".join( str(foo(i)) for i in tuple_ )
```

**Edit**

If writing for python < 2.4 use this since generator expressions were added in Python 2.4:

```
tuple_ = (a,b,c)
"\n".join([ str(foo(i)) for i in tuple_ ])
```

Comment: Note that you'll need to add `str()` around the `foo` call if `foo` doesn't return a string (necessary in OP's post as well though).

Answer (score 3):

As long as foo is a string:

```
 "\n".join(map(foo,tup))
```

Comment: It's my impression that map() is less pythonic than generator expressions, but perhaps I'm wrong